# How to make bootstrap column shrink to size of its contents

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a bootstrap column that I want to shrink to the height of its contents so another column can fill the space below it. Here is an image of what I am referring to:

[image]

I would like for the first column – holding both col-1 boxes – to shrink to the height of its contents so the "last" box can fill the space.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/MikeVMWork/pen/vYGqRqE?editors=1100)

```css
.box {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <div class="box">col-1</div>
      <div class="box">col-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="box">col-2</div>
      <div class="box">col-2</div>
      <div class="box">col-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <div class="box">last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I originally just put the 3rd bootstrap column as a child of the first column, but had to move away from that because of how the tabbing on the page worked. I need it to tab from col-1 to col-2 to col-3, the last one.

Comment: Why you  don't use two  big column  and put in your rows ?

Comment: @MMezlini because that wouldn't work for the mobile view where everything is in one column

Comment: why dint you use `d-flex` and in mobile view they all get `width100%` and `flex-fill` in inner div which will cover the white space

Comment: u mean like this ? https://imgur.com/a/fQt7LiL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "shrink" the size of one column in a grid layout without affecting the others, so we need to break down what you want to achieve. You are trying to work with 3 different orders:

- Visual order on larger screens: `col-1`, `last`, `col-2`
- Visual order on mobile: `col-1`, `col-2`, `last`
- Tab order on all screens:  `col-1`, `col-2`, `last`

The mobile order and tab order are the same (and also we can't change tab order responsively without JS), so we start with this as the basis of our display.

Then we want `last` to be positioned *before* the 3rd element of `col-2` on large screens, but *after* it on mobile, so we need to make those 2 elements work *relative to each other* instead of being part of the other cols.

**Working Example** - I've added `input`s to see the tab order. (Run in Full Page to see the cols)

```css
.box {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 25px;
}

input { width: 30px; } /* For demo only */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <div class="box"><input placeholder="1"> col-1</div>
      <div class="box"><input placeholder="2"> col-1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="box"><input placeholder="3"> col-2</div>
      <div class="box"><input placeholder="4"> col-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 order-md-last">
      <div class="box order-1"><input placeholder="5"> col-3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <div class="box"><input placeholder="6"> last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How this works:**

**1. Put the 3rd element from `col-2` in its own column `col-3`** which has the same classes as `col-2` so its looks exactly the same as when it was in col-2. It also displays exactly as it was on mobile screens. But now it can also be moved independently of `col-2`.

**2. Move the placement of the on larger screens**.  The step above makes it appear *before* the `last` column, so we can use [Bootstrap's order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes). Simply adding `order-md-last` to `col-3` makes it appear last on screens above the `md` breakpoint:

```
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 order-md-last">
      <div class="box order-1"><input placeholder="5"> col-3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is a super creative response. Thanks @FluffyKitten